# How do I find which end of the see-saw is either heavier or equal when the weight on the lever sits at different locations?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

How do I find which end of the see-saw is either heavier or equal when the weight on the lever sits at different locations?

In this photo each line throughout the lever represents 1 ft and whichever square is shaded blue within is 10 lb. The blank squares are absolutely empty and weigh nothing. To keep this simple we will say that virtually the whole see saw weighs nothing including the blank spaces. 
The left side of the fulcrum has a total of 90 lb but spaces out some of the weight between 12 ft while the right side of the fulcrum has 100 lb exactly 10 ft long with no spaces. How do I calculate which side is heavier if not equal?

[image: see saw example photo]

Comment: Hint: sum the torques from each element, on each side of the fulcrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are familiar with the concept of torque.

Torque($\Gamma$) = (Radius)x(Force) [Vector product]

Whilst considering the formula above one can state the fact that weights or forces(In the same direction) applied at equal distances from the fulcrum produce Torque equal in magnitude but opposite in direction; giving us net torque equal to zero.

Now in the system provided, apply the logic; we see;

Weights in 9,8,7,6,5,4,2,1  present on both the sides provide torques in opposite  direction but equal in magnitude(Effective torque due to them is zero)

The unbalanced torques are due to weights in 12,10 and 3.

By simple math,

(10*12)<((10*10)+(10*3))  [Comparing magnitudes since we know torques are in opposite
direction]

We see the right hand side is "Heavier" and therefore the see-saw tips towards it.